# Different voices text-to-speech

Tags: text-to-speech, epub

do you know any program or python code which can read text in different voices?
My text could be a play by Shakespeare e.g. like

Anna: Hello, I am Anna.

George: Hello, I am George.

where every person speaks in its own voice.

Which file format is used to program the change of voices?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Getting this done in python is possible, but text-to-speech is no trivial feature, so you need to get the general idea how it works and it depends in which context you need it. Like, if you just want to use it for yourself or if you want it implemented in a program you want to ship.

In general, there are text-to-speech engines out there. What you need is one of those installed on your operating system, and a python wrapper library that connects to it and enables it for your code to use. A thing like that is called a "wrapper library".

A quick search shows that there are indeed such wrapper libraries, for example "Pyttsx".

Now, you need to select a fitting combination of  text-to-speech-library (male voice, female voice) and ensure, that you can have a fitting python wrapper library that enables you to use it.

I can not give a better answer, maybe you want to update your question and add the following information: Target OS (Linux, Win, Apple), program will be shipped to retail customers or not (if so, you probably need a strategy to handle the platform dependency in the text-2-speech engine).